# Switching an SSRS Report Based on Parameter(s) Selected

Tags: reporting-services

I have two reports that are more or less very different from each other and yet have the same parameter list. The requirement is that these report should be in the same solution and users should be able to switch from one report to the other base on the condition of the Boolean parameter selected. Now I have an expression written but where it should go in the report body is where I don't know.
My expression:

```
=Switch(Parameters!Tax.Value = True,"Tax Todate Summary",Parameters!Tax.Value = False,"Line of Action(s)")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would build a "Navigation Report".  This would have the same parameter list, including that Boolean parameter.

The body of the report would contain two Subreport objects, for the two actual reports.  I would lay these out one above the other.  They would be the only objects on the Design pane of this report.

I would set the Visibility property of each Subreport object based on the Boolean parameter.  I would pass all the other parameter values through to each Subreport.

Comment: wouldn't this method have a performance impact? In that both reports will execute? If building a custom ssrs prompt page is not an option then a navigation report sounds good. However i wont immediately load both reports but rather have links to the two reports in the navigation report. This way you will avoid loading both reports. Just because the parameter list is the same doesn't necessarily mean that the queries used to populate the reports are. Links can also be placed on each report to reference the other report, that way the user wont need to go back to the navigation report.

Comment: Performance wasnt mentioned in the question, but if it is a serious concern then you could pass the Boolean parameter through to the subreports and use them to filter their datasets.

Comment: Performance is an issue with this method or implementation. Now we are looking at a better way of doing it. Any idea folks?

Comment: Ummm, have you tried what I wrote above? If you pass the parameter controlling the subreport visibility through to the subreports, and use it in their dataset WHERE clause, then subreports that are not visible will run in a split-second.